# jQuery menu toggleSlide with hover?

Tags: jquery, menu, slide

I have a menu in which only one item has a sublist. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Example One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I would like to `slideDown` the menu and stay on, when the mouse is on the menu or submenu. So the following is working good, but I want the same thing with hover and not click.

```
 $('#menu ul li').click(function() {
  $('#menu ul li ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {

  });
});
```

I tried with hover but it's very buggy, here is the code too:

```
$("#menu ul li").hover(
  function () {
    $("#menu ul li ul").slideDown('slow');
  },
  function () {
    $("#menu ul li ul").slideUp('slow');
  }
);
```

I tried to add `.stop(true, true)` or `$("#menu ul li ul").css("display", "block");` after the `slideDown` but it's still buggy.

CSS

```
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 30px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #8b4513;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#menu ul li a img {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: -4px;
}
#menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 151px;
    height: 90px;
    top: 59px;
    left: 300px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    background: url(gfx/submenu.png) no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
    height: 27px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 25px;
}
```

Comment: You mean like the guy on this site was doing with his Newsletter and Audio menu items?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539835/jquery-menu-slide-up-from-from-bottom-of-screen-on-hover

Comment: Hmm maybe, it's a little similar. I check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [it out live](http://jsfiddle.net/vanJA/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Example One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#menu ul li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).slideDown('slow');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');
  }
);
```

Comment: I added the CSS because I think there is a bug here. I tried into your code http://jsfiddle.net/vanJA/8/ but it's flickering when the mouse is over the submenu!

Comment: @MatthewK Try removing `.stop(true,true)` from mouseout i.e. from `.slideUp('slow')` and leave `.stop(true,true)` as it is in `.slideDown('slow')` ...Is that what you need...Try that out...

Comment: That really helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hover is triggered everytime the mouse moves over the element. Use enter/leave instead :

```
$("#menu ul li").mouseenter(
  function () {
    $("#menu ul li ul").slideDown('slow');
  }
);
$("#menu ul li").mouseleave(
  function () {
    $("#menu ul li ul").slideUp('slow');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMLyz/

```
$('#menu ul li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown('slow');
});

$('#menu ul li').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp('slow');
});
```