# jQuery menu on hover open submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to design something like the followingL

```
<ul class="top">
  <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu2</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">SubMenu2</a>
        <ul class="subsub">
          <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my idea is that if the Node has subNodes, then the submenu will open. So in this instance, if the user hovers on Menu2, the SubMenu1, SubMenu2, and SubMenu3 will appear, and if the user hovers on SubMenu2, SubSubMenu1, SubSubMenu2 will appear.

I have the following jQuery at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("ul.top li").hover(function () { //When trigger is hovered...
    if ($("ul.top li").hasClass("sub")) {
      $(this).parent().find("ul.sub").slideDown('fast').show();
      $(this).parent().hover(function () {}, function () {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.sub").slideUp('slow');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

However when I hover on Menu1, the submenus for Menu 2 are still opening.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Add your css, better make a jsfiddle

Comment: Are you sure you want `$(this).parent().find()` rather than just `$this.find()` as with the first, you'll go to all the way to the top and search down for ul.sub

Comment: Why use javascript to control your menu? There are tons of css menus out there http://css3menu.com/ that will work even if the user has javascript disabled.

Comment: I wish to do it in Jquery

Comment: I added alert("has class"); underneath if ($("ul.top li").hasClass(".sub")) { but none of them are returning this alert, so it seems like the class is not found

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228224/jquery-menu-toggleslide-with-hover

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228224/jquery-menu-toggleslide-with-hover

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of issues that need to be resolved. First, you should provide two arguments to the [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function, the first is a function for onmouseenter, the other is for onmouseleave.

Next, just tag all sub menus with the same class, e.g., `sub`. This will make writing you selectors much easier.

Use the [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function to only apply the animation to direct children of the item that the user is hovering over.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.top li").hover(function () { //When trigger is hovered...
        $(this).children("ul.sub").slideDown('fast');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("ul.sub").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd6kQ/1)**

Comment: how different is this answer from the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228224/jquery-menu-toggleslide-with-hover

Comment: Why it dance sometimes up and down when moving mouse cursor on one side or another? by the way nice logic. I upvoted you for that.